# Использование загруженной картинки в качестве фона рабочего стола

Tags: java, android, picasso

Наткнулся недавно на [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).
Вопрос: можно ли в одной из его функций `into` указать что-то для того, чтобы  установить картинку в качестве фона устройства? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходим [Target](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html), указываете его в into и у него есть метод который возвращает bitmap

```
private Target target = new Target() {
  @Override
  public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
     setBitmapWallpaper(bitmap);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBitmapFailed() {
  }
}
private void loadBitmap() {
   Picasso.with(this).load("url").into(target);
}
```

Comment: Спасиб! все разобрался, работает